# How would I add a sound from a url to a processing js program?

Tags: audio, processing.js

I've been trying to add a small game I've made in Khan Academy to a wix website, and I'm not sure how I would add audio. I'm looking for a way to possibly add simple music notes, and I was thinking using a url? Wix isn't really made for adding games, but I've managed to get the most important parts working.

I've tried looking up how to do this on the internet, but I can't find much on how I could use a url, or if wix has a better option. I was hoping that there was some kind of way to use a url link to add a note like middle c or d sharp but everything was a little inconclusive.

Comment: Please note that Processing.js was discontinued in December of 2018. That said, 11 years ago it involved using the JS "version" of Minim, so if you don't mind digging through ancient code: https://github.com/Pomax/Pjs-2D-Game-Engine/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mario.html